# Performing a transaction across multiple statements in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, innodb

I'm not sure if this is an issue with phpMyAdmin, or that I'm not fully understanding how transactions work, but I want to be able to step through a series of queries within a transaction, and either `ROLLBACK` or `COMMIT` based on the returned results. I'm using the InnoDB storage engine.

Here's a basic example;

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE students
SET lastname = "jones"
WHERE studentid = 1;

SELECT * FROM students;

ROLLBACK;
```

As a single query, this works entirely fine, and if I'm happy with the results, I could re-run the entire query with `COMMIT`.

However, if all these queries can be ran seperately, why does phpMyAdmin lose the transaction?

For example, if I do this;

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE students
SET lastname = "jones"
WHERE studentid = 1;

SELECT * FROM students;
```

Then this;

```
COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM students;
```

The update I made in the transaction is lost, and lastname retains its original value, as if the update never took place. I was under the impression that transactions can span multiple queries, and I've seen a couple of examples of this;

1: Entirely possible in [Navicat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9SLY3dly6E), a different IDE

2: Also possible in [PHP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNt9HPqDIVc) via MySQLi

Why then am I losing the transaction in phpMyAdmin, if transactions are able to span multiple individual queries?

**Edit 1:** After doing a bit of digging, it appears that there are two other ways a transaction can be implicitly ended in MySQL;

1. Disconnecting a client session will implicitly end the current
   transaction. Changes will be rolled back.
2. Killing a client session will implicitly end the current
   transaction. Changes will be rolled back.

Is it possible that phpMyAdmin is ending the client session after Go is hit and a query is submitted?

**Edit 2:**

Just to confirm this is just a phpMyAdmin-specific issue, I ran the same query across multiple seperate queries in MySQL Workbench, and it worked exactly as intended, retaining the transaction, so it appears to be a failure on phpMyAdmin's part.

Comment: Are you performing the queries in separate request in phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible that phpMyAdmin is ending the client session after Go is hit and a query is submitted?

That is pretty much how PHP works. You send the request, it get's processed, and once done, everything (including MySQL connections) gets thrown away. With next request, you start afresh.

There is a feature called [persistent connections](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php), but that is as well doing it's clean up. Otherwise the code would have to somehow handle giving the same user the same connection. Which could prove very difficult given the way PHP works.

Comment: Ah, I see. So it's more of a PHP issue than an IDE-specific issue. That would explain why it appears only to affect phpMyAdmin. I didn't consider that phpMyAdmin would close every connection after a query is run, but when you consider the language it's built on, it makes sense. I think this answers my question.

Comment: It's not really PHP's fault; it is the basic design of web servers to be "stateless".  Since PHP (and phpmyadmin) are running in that stateless environment, they _cannot_ remember anything.  (OK, `$_SESSION` may be a workaround, but not a good one.)

Comment: phpmyadmin is a handy tool.  But you really need a real programming language to do transactional processing.